# How to oracle DB using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting. Can you please help to connect to an Oracle DB using putty.

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
SQLPLUS hr/tiger <<EOF
select first_name from employees;
EOF
```

When I execute the code it's showing:

> SQLPLUS: command not  found

Can you please help me for that?
Thank you

Comment: That error is bash telling you it doesn't know where the SQLPLUS executable is located. You need to use a full path, i.e. `/usr/bin/SQLPLUS` (or wherever you have it installed) or include the directory in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm) tells me that the CLI binary's name is `sqlplus`, not `SQLPLUS` - case generally matters in the Unix world.